# Trouble automating email from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to google script and cannot work out why my script is not functioning. When I try to run the code I get the following error code -

TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code"

If anybody could give a novice some help that would be greatly appreciated!

```
function sendEmail(event){
var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
if(sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1') {
 // if it's not the correct sheet we end the function here
 return;
 }
 var range = event.range;
 var row = range.getRow(); // we get the index of the row of the 
edited 
 cell
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A" + row + ":C" + row);
var values = dataRange.getValues();
var rowValues = values[0];
var recipient = rowValues[0];
var email = rowValues[1];
var refillsNumber = rowValues[2];
if (refillsNumber = 2) {
 // if 'refillsNumber' is not equal to 2 we end the function here
var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n'+ 'You have ' + 
refillsNumber + ' remaining would you like to buy more?' + '\n\n' + 
'Kind regards,' + '\n\n' + 'The revol team.';
var subject = 'Refill reminder';
MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message);
return
 }
if (refillsNumber !== 0) {
return}
var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n'+ 'You have ' + 
refillsNumber + ' remaining would you like to buy more? If not then 
would you like to end your subsription?' + '\n\n' + 'Kind regards,' 
+ '\n\n' + 'The revol team.';
var subject = 'Refill reminder';
MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message);
return
}

// in addition to this script which aims to send an email to the 
customer when they only have 2 refill remaining - 
/// I also want to set up a function that sends an email when they 
have 0 refills remaining
```

Comment: Though I don't have any knowledge about google-apps-script, I can guess this error message could be because the event is null i.e. not defined.

Comment: Could you include some detail on what exactly your code is supposed to be doing here?

Answer (score 0):

**Send Emails by Editing Column C**

I changed the Sheet name and added an extra condition. I also commented out the MailApp.sends and replaced them with writes to the sidebar so that I could test it without trying to send emails.

You will need to create an onEdit trigger for this function.

```
function sendMailOnEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet2' || event.range.columnStart!=3) {return;}
  var range=event.range;
  var row=range.rowStart;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,3);
  var values=dataRange.getValues();
  var rowValues=values[0];
  var recipient = rowValues[0];
  var email = rowValues[1];
  var refillsNumber = rowValues[2];
  if (refillsNumber==2) {
    var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n'+ 'You have ' + refillsNumber + ' remaining would you like to buy more?' + '\n\n' + 'Kind regards,' + '\n\n' + 'The revol team.';
    var subject = 'Refill reminder';
    //MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message);
    var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />Email: %s<br />Subject: %s<br />message: %s<br /><hr>', email,subject,message);
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
    return
  }
  if (refillsNumber !== 0) {return}
  var message = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n\n'+ 'You have ' + refillsNumber + ' remaining would you like to buy more? If not then would you like to end your subsription?' + '\n\n' + 'Kind regards,' + '\n\n' + 'The revol team.';
  var subject = 'Refill reminder';
  //MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,message);
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />Email: %s<br />Subject: %s<br />message: %s<br /><hr>', email,subject,message);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
  
}
```

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

> And let me remind you that you cannot run this function without an event object.

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper that's sorted it!